# Upload remoto automático de arquivo zipado em PHP

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

Possuo um sistema de e-commerce em PHP instalado para diversos clientes. Porém, toda vez que faço uma atualização no sistema, tenho que manualmente subir os arquivos novos para todos os clientes.

Eu gostaria de automatizar isso. Uma solução que pensei foi em subir em um único local um arquivo ZIP com as atualizações, e colocar no sistema de cada loja a função "Atualizar". Basicamente pegaria o arquivo zipado com as atualizações em meu servidor, descompactaria no servidor do cliente, sobrepondo os arquivos antigos.

A parte em que quero ajuda é:

- No acesso remoto para cópia do arquivo (se necessário)
- Descompactação do mesmo de maneira que sobreponha os antigos arquivos, sem perder os atributos dos mesmos (755 para pasta e 644 para arquivos)

Alguma sugestão?

Grato desde já!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução passa por ter no lado dos clientes um ficheiro cujo código é chamado quando o cliente clica num botão "Actualizar".

Esse código ao ser chamado para execução terá que aceder à máquina remota, fazer o download do ficheiro com as actualizações e descomprimir o mesmo.

## Aceder à máquina remota

Para aceder à máquina remota, podemos utilizar cURL que através da função em baixo, podemos recorrer a autenticação ou não consoante o teu caso:

```
/**
 * cURL - Recolher ficheiro remoto
 *
 * Função recorrendo a cURL para recolher um ficheiro
 * numa máquina remota com ou sem autenticação.
 *
 * @param string $remotePath      Caminho remoto incluindo ficheiro
 * @param string $localPath       Caminho local incluindo ficheiro
 * @param array $access           Matriz com credenciais de acesso (usr;pwd)
 * @param boolean $overwrite      Se deve subscrever o ficheiro existente
 *
 * @return boolean                Estado da operação
 */
function recolherFicheiroRemotoCurl($remotePath, $localPath, $access = null, $overwrite = false) {

  // devolve TRUE se o ficheiro local existe e não é para subscrever
  if (is_file($remotePath) && !$overwrite) {

    return TRUE;
  }
  else {

    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $remotePath);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if ($access) {
      curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $access["username"].":".$access["password"]);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    if ($buffer != false) {
      file_put_contents($localPath, $buffer);
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

[PHP cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

## Unzip com subscrição dos ficheiros

Para correr o `unzip` subscrevendo ficheiros existentes, basta passar o parâmetro `-o`:

```
exec ('unzip -o ' . $ficheiro);
```

[Manpage para o UNZIP](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/unzip/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

---

## Solução

Podemos então ter um PHP no lado de cada cliente que é executado a pedido do mesmo para actualizar os ficheiros:

```
<?php

// Onde fica
$localPath = "caminho/local/do/ficheiro.zip";

// Onde está
$remotePath = "caminho/remoto/do/ficheiro.zip";

// Ir buscar
if (recolherFicheiroRemotoCurl($remotePath, $localPath) {

  // Se ficheiro local existe
  if (is_file($localPath)) {

    // Correr unzip
    exec('unzip -o ' . $localPath, $output, $return_value);

   // podes aceder à variável $output para ver o output da execução
   // podes aceder à variável $return_value para ver o código devolvido
  }
}

?>
```

---

**Notas:**

Para que o uso do código em cima possa ser utilizado, deverá estar instalado em cada cliente:

- PHP Client URL Library (cURL)
- unzip

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Serviu como uma luva!

Comment: @Szag-Ot É sempre um prazer ajudar :)

Comment: Parceiro, um problema: só consigo executar o comando unzip via exec do PHP se as pastas estiverem com permissão 777. Isso não é bom. Como faço para executar o comando com o usuário de root (eu possuo a senha) ou dar ao usuário plenos poderes para gravação dos arquivos?

Comment: @Szag-Ot Se queres executar o comando com privilégios elevados, o ideal será estabeleceres a ligação com autenticação, fazendo uso das credênciais de acesso de um utilizador com os previlégios necessários. **Não recomendo mesmo mesmo mesmo nada** que uses o PHP `exec()` com parametros para elevar as permissões do script a executar, é um sério problema de segurança.

Comment: Concordo, mas deixar as pastas com permissão 777 também.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: @Szag-Ot Não precisas ter as pastas com `777`, precisas que o utilizador que as vai manipular seja o mesmo que as criou ou seja um utilizador do mesmo grupo.

Comment: O utilizador é do mesmo grupo/proprietário. Ainda assim o exec retorna um erro a menos q as pastas e arquivos estejam em 777... aí ele permite a alteração

Comment: já vi qual o problema. Com "ls -l" dá pra ver que os arquivos criados pelo php estão sendo salvos com owner "nobody", e não com o owner "tmwe" que é o proprietários da conta teste. Sabe como configuro o owner em que o PHP é executado? A Plataforma é o WHM/CPanel.

Comment: Veja em detahes o problema aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23734/servidor-configurado-como-dso-qual-a-melhor-alternativa-para-permiss%C3%B5es-de-past

Comment: @Szag-Ot O Apache corre com `nobody` por defeito, podes no entanto aceder a `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` e alterar o `User` e `Group` para o que pretendes. Precisas fazer _restart_ após a alteração. De igual forma deverás actualizar a _ownership_ dos ficheiros e pastas para que tudo fique em condições.

Comment: Mas neste caso eu teria um problema, posto que em meu servidor dedicado possuo várias contas (uma para cada cliente). Essa solução resolveria para apenas 1 destas contas, mas não para as demais que possuem owner diferentes

Comment: @Szag-Ot Uma vez que abriste uma pergunta para lidar com este problema (e fizeste mt bem), eu vou elaborar uma resposta mais detalhada com uma solução para o teu caso.