# Como Criar uma nova Conta (Domínio) via SSH?

Tags: php, ssh, cpanel

Há um tempo atrás fiz uma pergunta - já resolvida - referente a como fazer uma atualização automática remotamente usando PHP ([Veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23163/upload-remoto-autom%C3%A1tico-de-arquivo-zipado-em-php/23171))

Agora eu gostaria de criar via SSH uma nova conta no servidor, a fim de replicar o sistema.

Ou seja, o cliente compraria o sistema no site, e o script PHP criaria (fazendo uso de exec, isto é, comandos SSH, se não houver um modo melhor) uma nova conta para este cliente, instalaria o sistema e deixaria a loja pronta para uso.

O meu servidor usa o sistema WHM/CPanel. Ou seja, ao ser criada a nova conta, o CPanel deve ser instalado nesta nova conta corretamente.

Como fazer isso?

Apenas o comando (ou conjuntos de comandos) SSH para a criação de uma nova conta/domínio já seria o suficiente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Criar conta cPanel via terminal

O cPanel vem com um script chamado [`createacct`](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/CreateAccount) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para criar contas a partir da linha de comandos. Podes fazer uso do mesmo para resolver a questão da criação da conta:

```
/scripts/createacct example.com utilizador password
```

O problema com este comando quando queremos utilizar o mesmo a partir de um *script* é o facto de ele pedir confirmação de algumas coisas aquando da sua execução.

Isto pode ser contornado conforme podemos ler [neste tópico](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/createacct-155958.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> do forum da cPanel que nos indica um link para:

[Como tornar o `/scripts/createacct` não-interactivo](http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/cpanel/createacct-non-interactive) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

```
PKGRESTORE=1 /scripts/createacct example.com utilizador password

└─────┬────┘ └─────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┘
executar em                     o comando para
  modo não                   criação de uma conta
interactivo                  a partir do terminal
```

---

#### PHP e SSH

Para fazeres uso de SSH através do PHP, assumindo ser a tua ideia, precisas de instalar a seguinte extensão PECL:

[PHP SSH2 Installing/Configuring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Depois basta estabeleceres uma ligação e executares o *script* que contém o comando em cima indicado.

Consulta o [manual PHP Secure Shell2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para veres como fazer cada um dos passos. Ia colocar aqui, mas fica extenso e se não conheces, vais sempre precisar de ler o manual.

---

### PHP e SSH (sem instalar a extenção)

Se precisar de te conectar a um servidor via SSH mas não tens possibilidade de instalar a extensão ssh2, a seguinte implementação em PHP puro pode resolver a tua questão:

[PHP Secure Communications Library - Net_SSH](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

**Exemplo:**

```php
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
if (!$ssh->login('utilizador', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Falhou');
}

echo $ssh->exec('meuScript');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```